How to join tables and group the results using LINQ?
I have a table of Products and a table of Product_Images with a one to many relation (one product can have multiple images) and I am trying to retrieve all products with their related images. So far I have:
 var results = (from p in _context.Products
                join i in _context.Product_Images on p.Id equals i.Product.Id
                select new
                {
                    p,
                    i
                }).ToList();

However that returns separate results for each image, even if they are related to the same product:
{product1, product1Img1}
{product1, product1Img2}
{product1, product1Img3}

I need the results to contain the product and a list of all its related images like so:
{product1, [product1Img1, product1Img2, product1Img3]}
{product2, [product2Img1, product2Img2, product2Img3]}
{product3, [product3Img1, product3Img2, product3Img3]}

I have tried using group by on the images after joining the tables but get either a "The method 'GroupBy' is not supported." or "The 'GroupJoin' operation must be followed by a 'SelectMany' operation where the collection selector is invoking the 'DefaultIfEmpty' method." exception, and I can only assume my syntax is incorrect.

So, Product do not have navigation propety Images?

If not, add it. It solves all of these problems.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv if I add an Images navigation property, how should my query change to get the results I want? or would my query work as is?

@GertArnold would my query need to change too? or should it work as is?


I have a table of Products and a table of Product_Images with a one to
many relation (one product can have multiple images)

It would be helpful if you could share the definition of your relevant class. This would allow to better understand the construction of your POCO class.
However, I am not sure how that's look like. But based on your description, if you have one product with many product image, then your Product and ProductImage class construction should be as following:
Model:
public class ProductTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
}

public class ProductImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}


I have tried using group by on the images after joining the tables but
get either a "The method 'GroupBy' is not supported." or "The
'GroupJoin' operation must be followed by a 'SelectMany' operation
where the collection selector is invoking the 'DefaultIfEmpty'
method."

The errors you're encountering likely arise from attempting to use LINQ-to-Entities operations that aren't supported by the underlying provider (in thisscenario EF Core) in the way you've structured your query.
This might be happen, when trying to use GroupBy in a way that EF Core cannot translate to SQL. You may know, GroupJoin method in EF Core is typically used to perform a left join, and it needs to be followed by SelectMany with DefaultIfEmpty to handle cases where there might be no matching records in the joined table. But, your query pattern does not directly translate to grouping and aggregating in SQL as a result you are getting that error.
I have tried in following way and got the expected result.
You could update your join for products and their images, and the results are grouped into an anonymous object containing the product and its list of images.
Let's have a look at the implementation:
Demo Data:
var products = new List<ProductTable>
 {
     new ProductTable { Id = 1, Name = "Product1" },
     new ProductTable { Id = 2, Name = "Product2" },
     new ProductTable { Id = 3, Name = "Product3" }
 };

 var productImages = new List<ProductImage>
 {
     new ProductImage { Id = 1, ProductId = 1, ImageUrl = "product1Img1.jpg" },
     new ProductImage { Id = 2, ProductId = 1, ImageUrl = "product1Img2.jpg" },
     new ProductImage { Id = 3, ProductId = 1, ImageUrl = "product1Img3.jpg" },
     new ProductImage { Id = 4, ProductId = 2, ImageUrl = "product2Img1.jpg" },
     new ProductImage { Id = 5, ProductId = 2, ImageUrl = "product2Img2.jpg" },
     new ProductImage { Id = 6, ProductId = 3, ImageUrl = "product3Img1.jpg" }
 };

Updated query:
var results = from p in products
              join i in productImages on p.Id equals i.ProductId into images
              select new
              {
                  Product = p,
                  Images = images.ToList()
              };


var resultsList = results.ToList();

Note: As you can see, I have grouped the images into an anonymous object containing the product and its list of images.
Demo Controller:
public IActionResult GetProductWithImages()
{
    
    var products = new List<ProductTable>
    {
        new ProductTable { Id = 1, Name = "Product1" },
        new ProductTable { Id = 2, Name = "Product2" },
        new ProductTable { Id = 3, Name = "Product3" }
    };

    var productImages = new List<ProductImage>
    {
        new ProductImage { Id = 1, ProductId = 1, ImageUrl = "product1Img1.jpg" },
        new ProductImage { Id = 2, ProductId = 1, ImageUrl = "product1Img2.jpg" },
        new ProductImage { Id = 3, ProductId = 1, ImageUrl = "product1Img3.jpg" },
        new ProductImage { Id = 4, ProductId = 2, ImageUrl = "product2Img1.jpg" },
        new ProductImage { Id = 5, ProductId = 2, ImageUrl = "product2Img2.jpg" },
        new ProductImage { Id = 6, ProductId = 3, ImageUrl = "product3Img1.jpg" }
    };

   
    var results = from p in products
                  join i in productImages on p.Id equals i.ProductId into images
                  select new
                  {
                      Product = p,
                      Images = images.ToList()
                  };

    
    var resultsList = results.ToList();
    return Json(resultsList);
}

Output:


Note: Please refer to this official document for additional reference.

your example makes perfect sense although I still get the 'GroupJoin must be followed by a SelectMany operation' exception with my data. Unfortunately I don't have control over the Product and Image classes. These tables are from Dynamics 365/Dataverse and the classes get auto generated. Is there anything else I could try?

When you are saying "You don't have control over the Product and Image classe" then how you are accessing _context.Products and _context.Product_Images? We still could keep the daynamics 365 class as it is and can inherit to a new class then based on the requirement we can do whatever we need. You could check this example

I just meant that I don't have control over how the classes are constructed, I have to use them as they are. I may have to go with the wrapper class option if nothing else works but it seems like it shouldn't be necessary for this.  Do you have any final thoughts on why the query you provided is giving me a GroupJoin exception? I imagine it has to be an issue with the way the dynamic 365 classes/tables are being constructed?

If I were in a situation where I don't have control over a class, but my code still needs to work with its data, using a wrapper class would be a convenient approach and I usually to it in order to keep the code clean and readble.

If you have a navigation property Product.Images, your query can be written as follows:
var results = 
    (from p in _context.Products
    select new
    {
        Product = p,
        Images = p.Images.ToList()
    }).ToList();

If defining a navigation property is not feasible, you can achieve the same result with the following query:
var results = 
    (from p in _context.Products
    select new
    {
        Product = p,
        Images = _context.Product_Images
            .Where(pi => pi.ProductId == p.Id)
            .ToList()
    }).ToList();

In this scenario, GroupJoin is not necessary because EF Core currently has poor support for this operator.
